# How to remove HTML tags, but preserve text, and then later replace the tags?

Tags: jquery

```
<ruby><rb>自分</rb><rp>（</rp><rt>じぶん</rt><rp>）</rp></ruby>
```

I want to remove `<ruby>` tags, but I want to keep the contents. I want to do it with all `<ruby>` tags on the page.

I don't even know how to try, I had the idea to keep the HTML content in a variable, remove the `<ruby>` tags with `hide()`, and splash the text again, but I don't know how to re-insert it in a specific section of text. Also, I'm struggling with `each`.

I'd also like to remember where the tags were removed, so I can get them back later with a click.

Comment: The question was edited so that the tags are removed but are remembered so that they can be re-wrapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `unwrap` function:

`$('ruby').unwrap();`

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

**EDIT:**

How about similarly following the tutorial example in the above link?

```
pTags = $('ruby');

if ( pTags.parent().is("span") ) {
  pTags.unwrap();
  pTags.wrap("<ruby></ruby>");
} else {
  pTags.unwrap();
  pTags.wrap("<span class='unwrapped_ruby'></span>");
}
```

Unwrap the `<ruby>` tag and wrap it with a placeholder `<span>` tag.

**Update 1:**

Well, my previous code had the right "pseudocode", but I tested it and it wasn't working properly. Instead I had to do something like this:

```
pTags = $('ruby');
var content = pTags.contents();

$("button").click(function () {
    if (content.parent().is("span")) {
        content.unwrap().wrapAll("<ruby></ruby>");
    } else {
        content.unwrap().wrapAll("<span class='unwrapped_ruby'></span>");
    }
});
```

**Update 2:**

Update 1 didn't take into consider multiple `<ruby>` tags. I have updated the code so that it works for multiple ruby tags as well as nested `<ruby>` tags!

```
var wrapper = $('ruby');
var content;

$("button").click(function () {
    wrapper.each(function () {
        content = $(this).contents();
        if (content.parent().is("span")) {
            content.unwrap().wrapAll("<ruby></ruby>");
            wrapper = $('ruby');
        } else {
            content.unwrap().wrapAll("<span class='unwrapped_ruby'></span>");
            wrapper = $('span.unwrapped_ruby');
        }
    });

});
```

Try the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/WytJV/)

Comment: Is it possible to remember where the tags were removed, so I can get then back later?

Comment: Copy the .html() to a JS variable.

Comment: It doesn't work with more `<ruby>` tags, it swaps the contents around.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to remove the ruby tags, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cont = $('ruby').contents().unwrap();
    $('html').append(cont)
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HzVZx/embedded/result/)**